# Limit of a subsequence of a Cauchy sequence defined by a recurrence relation

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

This is an exercise from the lecture slides of the calculus course I'm taking. I can't figure this one out so I'm posting it here! [image]

I know the sequence converges by Cauchy criterion from the fact that the $|x_n - x_{n+1}| < \frac{1}{2^n}$ for all natural number $n$ implies the sequence is Cauchy.

The subsequence ${x_{2n+1}}$ is supposed to be easy to evaluate...

Comment: Do you already know the sum of a geometric series?

Comment: Yes I used it to prove that $|x_n - x_{n+1}| < \frac{1}{2^n}$ for all $n$ is Cauchy.

Comment: Are you able to solve that recurrence?

Comment: Now write $$x_n = x_1 + \sum_{k = 2}^n (x_k - x_{k-1}).$$